# How can I trace an ANALYSIS_EXPORT error when building QGIS?

Tags: qgis

When building qgis1.8 using QT 4.7.4, I encountered the following error. I am unable to trace it:

```
src/analysis/raster/qgsrastercalculator.h:31:24: error: variable ‘ANALYSIS_EXPORT QgsRasterCalculatorEntry’ has initializer but incomplete type
```

Earlier there was an error for `CORE_EXPORT` too, i have solved it using `DEFINES += GUI_EXPORT= CORE_EXPORT=`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What platform/OS are you using?

Comment: Fedora with QT 4.7.4